# How put Firebase object to state in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, rebase

I'm learning react and I'm having difficulty putting data from Firebase into the application state. I use Rebase but I am open to any solution!
[image: FireBase]

still have an error similar to this one :
[image: error]

Thank you for your help !

Here is the code :

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    user:'',
    vampires: {}
  }

  componentDidMount() {

    if(this.state.user === ''){
      firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user =>  {
        if(user){
            this.handleUserLogin({ user })
            this.setVampires({ user })
        } else {
          console.log('error')
        }
      })
    }
  }

  setVampires = async (authData) => {
    console.log(this.state.user)
    await base.fetch(`/${authData.user.uid}/vampires`, { context: this })
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data)
      let vampires = this.state.vampires;
      vampires = {..._.cloneDeep(data)};
      this.setState({vampires: {vampires}})
    })
  }

  handleUserLogin = async authData => {
    this.setState({user: authData.user.uid})
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Firebase data is returned as an Object, with properties `VampM5-....`. React expects that you pass any repeated data as an array, not as an object.

So you'll need to convert the data from Firebase to an array, for example with:

```
await base.fetch(`/${authData.user.uid}/vampires`, { context: this })
.then(data => {
  vampires = [];
  data.forEach((child) => {
    vampires.push({ ...child.val(), ".key": child.key });
  })
  this.setState({ vampires: vampires })
})
```

Comment: It didn't work, it would take a method that recursively copies children.

Finally I have symplified my stage, that my object no longer has several children

Comment: Good to hear you found another way to make it work @JamiNejem. It would be good if you could post the code and explanation of that solution as a self-answer, so that others can benefit from it too.